# How can I autofill text boxes by selecting a row in a datagridview (vb.net) (sql)

Tags: vb.net

I want my textboxes to auto fill when I select a row. Here is an example...

| ID | Firstname | Lastname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2435 | timmy | turner |

I click on row with ID = 1 ---> TextBox1.text = 2435

I have tried

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.SelectedRows
        TextBox1.Text = row.Cells(0).value
    Next
```

I know this is completely wrong but I think I have the right idea.

Comment: Take a read of [DataGridView.SelectionChanged Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionchanged?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to handle the `SelectionChanged` event of the DataGridView.

```
Private Sub MyDataGridView_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyDataGridView.SelectionChanged

    With MyDataGridView

        ' Ensure one and only one row is selected.
        If .SelectedRows IsNot Nothing AndAlso .SelectedRows.Count = 1 Then

            Dim row As DataGridViewRow = .SelectedRows(0)

            TextBox1.Text = row.Cells(0).Value.ToString()
            TextBox2.Text = row.Cells(1).Value.ToString()

        End If

    End With
        
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm getting an error, "Value is not a member of DataGridViewRow"

Comment: Oops. Forgot `Cells()` in  there. I typed my answer from memory.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `BindingSource`, you can apply the same DataSource to several controls and they will remain synced.

The constructor of `Binding` takes

- The property you want to bind, in this case `Text`
- The source of the data, in this case the BindingSource, `bs`
- The field name of the column in the DataTable that you want to bind, in this case `Name` for one and `Type` for another. (fields in my database table)

As you select rows in the DataGridView, the TextBoxes will sync.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dt = LoadCoffeeTable()
    Dim bs As New BindingSource(dt, Nothing)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = bs
    TextBox1.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", bs, "Name"))
    TextBox2.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", bs, "Type"))
End Sub
```